# Are username and password necessary to retrieve the latest SVN commit?

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

Why didn't the Subversion (SVN) command line client need the username and password when running the following command:

```
svn log -q --limit 1 http://example/svn/project_name/trunk --xml
```

Answer (score 1):

**It depend on repository settings** (i think is possibile authorize anonymous login) but if you have already used the svn client (also a graphical client) for accessing that repository and you have saved your credentials, svn command don't ask you again.

You can remove authentication from graphical client and try the svn command again.

Here an example for TortoiseSVN:

[image]

Comment: actually i am thinking of that but when i browse the documentation it says we didn't have to using username or password.. maybe just for the xml data (last commit, revision, and time) didn't need the username password for such as information

Comment: can you post a link of this documentation page?